# Hashing a column in Teradata

Tags: sas, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I need to hash a column in Teradata.
I have the follwing code in SAS and i would like the output to be equal:

```
COLUMN_HASH = upcase(put(sha256(strip(COLUMN)), hex64.));
```

But i cannot use SAS to insert the records to teradata, it would need to be done from a teradata table to another.

I would like to know if something similar to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683533/hash-a-column-in-postgres-using-sha-256) exist in teradata because i haven't found something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: There's just the internal hashing algorithm `HASHROW(column)`, but it's 32-bit only. For SHA the DBA needs to install a UDF (which can be found on the web or by asking Teradata support)