How can you generate a SHA-256 hash from a JSONB column in Postgres?
I have a table in my Postgres DB that has a JSONB column and I want to automatically generate a SHA-256 hash of it.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car (
  metadata JSONB,
  hash TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (encode(sha256(metadata), 'hex')) STORED,
);

I get this error:
ERROR: function sha256(jsonb) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried casting the column as BYTEA.
hash TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (encode(sha256(metadata::BYTEA), 'hex')) STORED

But I get this error:
ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to bytea

Is this possible?

select sha256('[1,2,3]'::jsonb::text::bytea);  \xa36b1f2c3f84522dd1005145646617d7054c0851e97c72a039c0bdfac9fa07f3.

There are more problems. 'hex' is a valid 2nd parameter to encode(), not to sha256(). But why would you use encode() in the first place?  What's the purpose of the added hash?

@ErwinBrandstetter Good catch. My code had the correct params but I had written the syntax in the issue incorrectly, so I have updated my question. However, the errors remain. I'm using encode as referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62926616/2262604

@AdrianKlaver Casting it to TEXT before casting it to BYTEA worked. Do you want to add that as an answer? Specifically hash TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (encode(sha256(metadata::TEXT::BYTEA), 'hex')) STORED

@MichaelLynch You really shouldn't encode it as a text - store the smaller (and faster) bytea instead. You should use text only if there are external constraints requiring it, such as being forced to use an ORM that can handle nothing but text.
